# Is there a less verbose way to retrieve non deprecated enum values?

Tags: java, reflection, enums, deprecated

See my code below. I have an `enum` where some values are marked deprecated. I need a `Collection` of all the values of the `enum` which are not deprecated.
I managed to accomplish the task using reflection, but it looks too verbose to me.
Is there a cleaner way to define the presence of the `@Deprecated` tag ?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DeprecatedEnumValues {

public enum MyEnum {
    AA,
    BB,
    @Deprecated CC,
    DD,
    @Deprecated EE,
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<MyEnum> myNonDeprecatedEnumValues = new ArrayList<MyEnum>();

    for (Field field : MyEnum.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isEnumConstant() && !field.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class)) {
            myNonDeprecatedEnumValues.add(MyEnum.valueOf(field.getName()));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myNonDeprecatedEnumValues);
}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look terribly verbose to me (for Java).  I haven't worked a ton with reflection in Java, but that is how I would do it.

Comment: I would have used `&&` instead of `&` but otherwise only using shorter names would make it shorter.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, thanks. My coding accuracy is a bit sloppy on friday afternoon ;-) I will edit the sample code.

Comment: For a moment I thought you had invented an AND-NOT operator `&!`

Answer (score 8):

Here is a more concise solution using streams:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    AA,
    BB,
    @Deprecated CC,
    DD,
    @Deprecated EE,

    /**
     * Retrieve enum values without the @Deprecated annotation
     */
    public static List<MyEnum> nonDeprecatedValues() {
        return Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).filter(value -> {
            try {
                Field field = MyEnum.class.getField(value.name());
                return !field.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not that big of a difference but you could place your analysis into the `enum` itself so it's more convenient to use and the `if`-clause becomes simpler:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DeprecatedEnumValues {

    public enum MyEnum {
        AA, 
        BB, 
        @Deprecated CC, 
        DD, 
        @Deprecated EE;

        public static List<MyEnum> getNonDepricatedEnumValues(){
            List<MyEnum> myNonDeprecatedEnumValues = new ArrayList<MyEnum>();

            for (MyEnum enumValue : MyEnum.values())
                try {
                    Field field = MyEnum.class.getField(enumValue.name());                      
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class))
                        continue;

                    myNonDeprecatedEnumValues.add(enumValue);                   
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {}
                // both cannot occure here..

            return myNonDeprecatedEnumValues;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.getNonDepricatedEnumValues());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I could not change the code of the Enum, because it was part of a library.

Comment: You can do the same in a method outside of the enum itself. Simply move the method into your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most effective implementation to get the non-deprecated enums with using the `static` block and Java 8 streams.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public enum MyEnum {
    AA,
    BB,
    @Deprecated
    CC,
    DD,
    @Deprecated
    EE;

    private static List<MyEnum> nonDeprecatedEnums;

    static {
        nonDeprecatedEnums = Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).filter(value -> {
            try {
                Field field = MyEnum.class.getField(value.name());
                return !field.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve enum values without the @Deprecated annotation
     */

    public static List<MyEnum> getNonDeprecatedEnums() {
        return nonDeprecatedEnums;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Impressive